# Build pjsip 2.10 using msys2

Tags: makefile, pjsip, mingw32, msys2

I'm compiling pjsip 2.10 using msys2:
1) open msys2 console: `C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd`
2) Run those to update:

```
pacman -Sy
pacman --needed -S bash pacman pacman-mirrors msys2-runtime
pacman -Su
pacman -S perl
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S base-devel
```

3) Restart msys2 console
4) export PATH="/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/:$PATH"
5) Config:

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/dist_mingw --disable-ffmpeg --enable-shared --disable-video --disable-speex-aec --disable-speex-aec --disable-g711-codec --disable-l16-codec --disable-gsm-codec --disable-g722-codec --disable-g7221-codec --disable-speex-codec --disable-ilbc-codec --disable-vpx --disable-opus --disable-libyuv --disable-libwebrtc
```

6) `make CFLAGS+="-DPJ_WIN32=1 -DPJ_M_I386=1 -D_LIB -DWIN32 -DPJ_M_I386=1"`
7) But error:

```
output/pjlib-x86_64-pc-msys/log.o:log.c:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `pj_time_decode'
output/pjlib-x86_64-pc-msys/ssl_sock_ossl.o:ssl_sock_ossl.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `pj_time_encode'
output/pjlib-x86_64-pc-msys/ssl_sock_dump.o:ssl_sock_dump.c:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `pj_time_decode'
output/pjlib-x86_64-pc-msys/ssl_sock_dump.o:ssl_sock_dump.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `pj_time_decode'
```

8) As I see `pj_time_encode` is in `pjproject-2.10\pjlib\src\pj\os_time_win32.c`but this file is not compiled. Instead, file `os_time_unix.c` was compiled. I think this is the cause. So how to make the file `os_time_win32.c` be compiled instead of `os_time_unix.c`.
I'm not good in makefile so this is hard to me to custom the build. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could ask the pjsip maintainer(s).If they support Windows builds, they should be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my MSYS environment PJSIP 2.10 compiles fine with (replace `x86_64-w64-mingw32` with `i686-w64-mingw32` for 32-bit):

```
./configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-shared --enable-libsamplerate --with-external-speex --with-external-gsm --with-external-srtp --with-external-pa &&
make dep &&
make &&
echo SUCCESS
```

I did compile the dependancies first myself, hence the `with-external-` flags.